# Getting build.gradle errors: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

I'm getting an error every time I try to use the forge mdk 1.8. The error is Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1. Before I got this error, I got a blue screen, likely because this error triggered. Here is my build.gradle:[imageone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHN9Z.png) [imagetwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH05p.png). Can someone please help me as this is very frustrating for me.

Comment: Try sharing code as code snippets instead of screenshots, it makes the question more readable and helps others to debug it.

Comment: I would have, but it wasnt lining up properly? Do you have a suggestion for how I fix this?